# Modify value of String in JNI NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

i have an int a = 20 in my java code

```
    public int a = 20 ;
```

then i had declared ndk & java native interface in my project witch can change value of int a = 20
to a= 100 , means that my native code change int a = 20 to 100 ;

```
    static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
public static native void myfunction (MyChangeActivity mclass);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_change);

    myfunction(this);
```

here is the c++ code id written

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_lotka_ndk_1hello_1world_MyChangeActivity_myfunction(
    JNIEnv *env ,
    jclass cls,
    jobject obj){
jclass myjclass = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jfieldID myjfield =  env->GetFieldID(myjclass, "a", "I") ;
env->SetIntField(obj, myjfield, 100);
}
```

finish

i had an integer which the value of it was 20

```
int a = 20
```

but after jni part a will increase to 100

***now my question is that how to do this with String***

i want this at begining

```
String b = "website.com"
```

and change it to

```
String b = "google.com"
```

i want everything by ndk and following method that which i declared at the top for int
but now i want string version of my code :)

tnks alot

Comment: Hello, you seem to be a new user trying to use the JNI. Have you read the [JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) and [Android-specific advice](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle is the same. You get the field ID, and then you modify the field with `Set*Field`.

[The signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) of the field is now `Ljava/lang/String;` instead of `I`. And instead of `SetIntField` you need to use `SetObjectField`.

And unless you already have a `jstring` with the desired contents, you'll have to create one with [`NewString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) or `NewStringUTF`.